# Epimorphism and generator of Mod-$ R $

Tags: category-theory, modules, epimorphisms

I am stuck with a question that should be very simple, because ALL the books and references that I have read say the same: ''is obvious and we will not prove it''.

Is the following statement: ''Let $ P $ a right $ R $-Module. Prove that if exists an epimorphism $ P^n \longrightarrow R $ for some integer $ n $, then $ P $ is a generator of the category Mod$ -R $.''

At first it seems simple: if $ N $ is a right $ R $-Module and $ S \subset N $ is a generator of $ N $, then $ N $ is isomorphic to a quotient $ R^{(S)} / K $ and so exists an epimorphism $ f : R^{(S)} \longrightarrow N $. On the other hand, we can extend the epimorphism $ g : P^n \longrightarrow R $ given in the statemente to an epimorphism $ \overline{g} : (P^n)^{(S)} \longrightarrow R^{(S)} $ by 
$$
\overline{g}((x_s)_{s \in S}) = 
(g(x_s))_{s \in S}
$$

Then we obtain an epimorphism
$$
f \circ \overline{g} : (P^n)^{(S)} \longrightarrow N
$$

That we need is to find an epimorphism $ P^{(I)} \longrightarrow N $ for some set $ I $. That is not exactly the obtained above.

I don't know how to solve this little problem.

Comment: It seems that you misread what _[generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(category_theory))_ means. It differs from a generating set of a module.

Comment: A right $ R $-Module $ P $ is a generator of Mod$ -R $ if for each right $ R $-Module $ N $ exist an epimorphism $ P^{(I)} \longrightarrow N $ for some set $ I $. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove that $(P^n)^{(S)}\cong (P^{(S)})^n$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1178785)

Comment: @AlanMuniz Really? Did you *read* the question?

Comment: @egreg : it's not $S^n$ though (take $S=\{*\}$ for instance ;) ) - of course it's probably just a typo of yours

Comment: @Max Thanks for noting